# How to distribute a self developed mac application?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I've developed an application on XCode, compiled and built it.
If I run the app on the same machine using Finder, it starts normally.
But if I copy the app to another machine and try to run it, the application does not start.
Is there another step that I forgot after building the application on XCode?
I think it seems to be a simple issue, but I really need some help on it...

Thanks!

Comment: Does the other machine have the same OS X version?  Does the app rely on a third-party framework?

Comment: Yes. If I build the app on the other machine, it works.

Comment: Did you compile for Release rather than Debug? Did you make sure Zero-Link is turned off?

Comment: I didn't find Zero-Link option. I'm using XCode 3.2.3. I compiled for release.

Comment: If I compile the same project on the target machine the app runs normally.

Answer (score 0):

On a machine where it doesn't start, open the Console utility, try launching your program, and see if any new messages appear in the Console window.

Comment: Yes, a "Permission denied" message appeared on that. Why? Do you know can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

OK, It was a very stupid error...
I was sending the app to the other machine through iChat. When the download completes the execute permission of the executable file inside the app is automatically removed.
So, I was trying to execute a non executable app.

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Package it then, as .dmg or whatever. Sending bundles directly isn't quite reliable.